# CSS3: Show a hidden text div when hovering a image div

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a image gallery only with css.

I want the text div to cover all of my "background-image" when I pass the cursor on it.
Right now the background of text does not cover it totally.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<style>

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.gridContainer {
width: 88.2%;
max-width: 1232px;
padding-left: 0.9%;
padding-right: 0.9%;
margin: auto;
}

#mainWrapper{
width:100%; 
}
.contentor{
display:block;
width:33.3%;
height:auto;
position:relative;
margin:0;
float:left;
}
.imagem{
display:block;    
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:auto;
left:0;
top:0;
}
.texto{
display:block;
z-index:100;
position:absolute;  
font-size: 3em;
font-weight:bold;
left:50%;
top:35%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align:center;
background: rgba(153, 102, 0, 0.6);
transition: opacity 2s;   /* efeito trans */
opacity:0;
}

.contentor:hover .texto{
  opacity:1;
}

}

 </style>
```

```
    <div class="contentor">
        <img class="imagem" src="IMGS/index_amb.jpg"/>
        <p class="texto">texto por cima</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contentor">
        <img class="imagem" src="IMGS/index_fuller.jpg"/>
        <p class="texto">texto por cima</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contentor">
        <img class="imagem" src="IMGS/index_ft_rain.jpg"/>
        <p class="texto">texto por cima</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contentor">
        <img class="imagem" src="IMGS/index_manual.jpg"/>
        <p class="texto">texto por cima</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contentor">
        <img class="imagem" src="IMGS/index_pecados.jpg"/>
        <p class="texto">texto por cima</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contentor">
        <img class="imagem" src="IMGS/index_e_r.jpg"/>
        <p class="texto">texto por cima</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jQuerys hover() and mouse over() methods.

Sorry. I haven't tested this but I would think that you would need to set the CSS element to .hidden and then use the mouseenter, mouseover event to reset the CSS.

Comment: Thanks ballbern, but has I said I'm trying to do it with css